# E/flutter ( 8115): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]

Tags: flutter, object-detection, yolov8

E/flutter ( 8115): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(100, Detection Error, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_images:0) with 4915200 bytes from a Java Buffer with 23040 bytes.

I am trying to integrate my yolov8 model into flutter using fluttervision package. When i saw my model in netron app it shows that my input image should be tensor: float32[1,3,640,640]
so i added a function to convert unit8 into float32 but still when i pick a image from gallery and try to perfrom detection this error comes up. I am attaching the code snippet of my code here pls help!!!

```
`code for image detection from gallary`
class YoloImageV8 extends StatefulWidget {
  final FlutterVision vision;
  const YoloImageV8({Key? key, required this.vision}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<YoloImageV8> createState() => _YoloImageV8State();
}

class _YoloImageV8State extends State<YoloImageV8> {

  Future<Uint8List> preprocessImage(File imageFile) async {
    final imageBytes = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
    final decodedImage = img.decodeImage(imageBytes);

    // Resize image to 640x640
    final resizedImage = img.copyResize(decodedImage!, width: 640, height: 640);

    // Convert to RGB format
    final pngBytes = img.encodePng(resizedImage!);

    // Normalize pixel values to [0, 1]
    final normalizedBytes = Float32List.fromList(pngBytes!.map((byte) => byte / 255.0).toList());

    // Expand dimensions to match [1, 3, 640, 640]
    final inputTensor = normalizedBytes.expand((value) => [value, value, value]).toList();
    final reshapedTensor = Float32List.fromList([1.0] + inputTensor);

    return Uint8List.fromList(reshapedTensor.map((value) => (value * 255).round()).toList());
  }


  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> yoloResults;
  File? imageFile;
  int imageHeight = 1;
  int imageWidth = 1;
  bool isLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadYoloModel().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        yoloResults = [];
        isLoaded = true;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() async {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Model not loaded, waiting for it"),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        imageFile != null ? Image.file(imageFile!) : const SizedBox(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: pickImage,
                child: const Text("Pick an image"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: yoloOnImage,
                child: const Text("Detect"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        ...displayBoxesAroundRecognizedObjects(size),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> loadYoloModel() async {
    await widget.vision.loadYoloModel(
        labels: 'assets/task1.txt',
        modelPath: 'assets/task1.tflite',
        modelVersion: "yolov8",
        quantization: false,
        numThreads: 2,
        useGpu: true);
    setState(() {
      isLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  Future<void> pickImage() async {
    final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    // Capture a photo
    final XFile? photo = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (photo != null) {
      setState(() {
        imageFile = File(photo.path);
      });
    }
  }

  yoloOnImage() async {
    yoloResults.clear();
    Uint8List byte = await imageFile!.readAsBytes();
    final image = await decodeImageFromList(byte);
    imageHeight = image.height;
    imageWidth = image.width;
    final result = await widget.vision.yoloOnImage(
        bytesList: byte,
        imageHeight: image.height,
        imageWidth: image.width,
        iouThreshold: 0.8,
        confThreshold: 0.4,
        classThreshold: 0.5);
    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        yoloResults = result;
      });
    }
  }

  List<Widget> displayBoxesAroundRecognizedObjects(Size screen) {
    if (yoloResults.isEmpty) return [];

    double factorX = screen.width / (imageWidth);
    double imgRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
    double newWidth = imageWidth * factorX;
    double newHeight = newWidth / imgRatio;
    double factorY = newHeight / (imageHeight);

    double pady = (screen.height - newHeight) / 2;

    Color colorPick = const Color.fromARGB(255, 50, 233, 30);
    return yoloResults.map((result) {
      return Positioned(
        left: result["box"][0] * factorX,
        top: result["box"][1] * factorY + pady,
        width: (result["box"][2] - result["box"][0]) * factorX,
        height: (result["box"][3] - result["box"][1]) * factorY,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.pink, width: 2.0),
          ),
          child: Text(
            "${result['tag']} ${(result['box'][4] * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%",
            style: TextStyle(
              background: Paint()..color = colorPick,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but from my (limited) experience meddling with cameraImage values never helped me. Are you doing all these conversions to get the yolo detections?

I spent so much time doing conversions but what worked for me finally was to adapt my solution to the image format.

If you're on android, ideally with the default YUV_420_888 format (which is the default on my Pixel 7 Pro atleast) works fine. When I converted that to NV21 format (I needed to do so for using google's ml_kit), I had to tweak my input bytelist accordingly.

I changed:

```
bytesList: cameraImage.planes.map((plane) => plane.bytes).toList()
```

to:

```
bytesList: [image.planes.first.bytes, Uint8List(0), Uint8List(0)]
```

Support online for this library (flutter libraries in general) is not the best, so hope this helps. Also, make sure you're awaiting for responses